# Positive sequence u such that $n^{a}u_{n}$ is not bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I'm looking for a *positive* sequence u such that $\Sigma u_{n}$ converges, and for all $a > 0$, the sequence $(u_{n}n^{a})$ is not bounded.

I've been trying to use log to create such a sequence (because it's slower than the $n^a$): $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$, $\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$, and so on, but I can't get what is required ...

Comment: Well, I believe that if $u_{n} = \frac{1}{(\log n)^{2}}$, then $\Sigma u_{n}$ does not converge. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u_n=\frac  1 {\ln n}$  if $n$ is of the type $2^{(2^{m})}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you ! I had tried the same idea but only with $2^{m}$, not $2^{(2^{m})}$, and it changes quite a lot ...